# Journey Builder - Which DE is email data is using?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I added a new field to the Entry DE that is used for a journey.  However after the change, I got a triggered send error from support like below.  During testing the email seemed to be fine.

```
Customer Key: XXXX

Description: Email One - Mil - aaaaaaaaaa

TS ListID: XXXX

JobID :XXXXXX

Error Message: ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentBlockByKey function call.
  Function Call: =ContentBlockbyKey("XXXX")
  See inner exception for details.
  Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR
 - from OMMCommon -->
```

I suspect that this happen because the content block that is calling the new field isn't yet available yet in the Entry DE?  Do I still need to create a new version of the journey so that the new field changes then applied to the Entry DE?

My understanding was that if the new field isn't being referred to in the journey then I don't need to create a new version of the journey as the email activity can refer to the DE just fine.

Hope the above make sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Correct you if you change the entry source de you need a new version

Comment: Thank you @EazyE. I will publish a new version of the journey and gives this a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes to the current entry source data extension would not be reflected in any running journey. The journey takes a snapshot of the DE configuration at the time of activation and doesn't update when you make a change.

So if you tried to make reference to a newly added field, through a personalization string this error would occur. However, you could use the AMPscript `lookup()` function as opposed to using a personalization string.

Comment: Thank you @EazyE for the tip.  I've created a new version and publish the journey with the refreshed Entry source DE.  It is as you said, that the changes can only be applied when a new journey is created.  Thanks again!